# Re-squash an OS under berryboot?

Tags: berryboot

My understanding of berryboot is that for each OS it has a "base" distro using squashfs, and any changes I make get saved as non-squashed files.

I'm using Debian Jessie as one of my OSs and have recently done an `apt-get upgrade`.  This results in using a lot of disk space (probably more than if there was no squashfs at all).

Is it possible in any way for me to merge the squashfs image with the later updates and make a fresh squashfs image?

Comment: With squashfs, you need to unpack the image, do the required modifications, then re-pack it.